# How to create List of CardViews with list?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, material-design, android-cardview

Please tell me how it is possible to make a list of lists. I tried to use Expandable listView but, unfortunately,I failed to create separate each group in the form of cards. Please tell me how it is possible to do both on the attached photo.

[image]

Comment: Dude i am working on same. Check this out http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-make-an-android-card-list/

Comment: Umfortunately, its simple cards, without listView inside i need. Thank`s!

Answer (score 0):

If number of cards and items isn't too big you can try something like this (creating 5 cards with 5 items):

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

    LinearLayout card = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.card, null);

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        View item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardItem, null);
        card.addView(item);
    }

    mainLayout.addView(card);
}
```

Offcourse you will need to create xml files (cardItem.xml, card.xml)

Comment: Problem can be in that: I need to create new item (CardView) by clicked some bottom, like "Create new", and listView, that located in this card, must have listView (data load from data base). Thank`s!

Comment: and new card need save after close application.